# Digital Ocean LAMP stack not working

Tags: php, mysql, apache2, lamp, digital-ocean

I created a Ubuntu 1GB/30GB Droplet with Ubuntu 16.10 x64
MYSQL: mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.16, for Linux (x86_64) using EditLine wrapper
APACHE VERSION: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
PHP: PHP 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.10.1 (cli) ( NTS )

Created SSH Login for SuperUser.
Installed LAMP using,the following steps:

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install tasksel
3. sudo tasksel install lamp-server

I have no files in the /etc/apache2/ folder
Tried installing with sudo apt-get install apache2 (says i already have newest version)

The index.html does not appear, just get "site cannot be reached"

Also when trying mysql -v i get a message "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

PHP is installed fine at PHP 7.0.13

I have been searching through various places, youbtube, digital ocean forums etc.. but no luck for a few days now.

checked memory and i have enough, there are no errors for memory shortages.

Comment: use mysql --version

Comment: ok so that shows its installed at least: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.16, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: also see if you could start apache  `sudo service apache2 start`

Comment: comes up with: Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. and the log says:  /etc/init.d/apache2: 46: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars

Comment: Now all i can suggest you to remove the current apache and install agaian `sudo apt-get remove apache2` and `sudo apt-get install apache2`

Answer (score 0):

why are you installing lampp when you are running Ubuntu server. just run this commands and you are good to go

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install apache2

sudo apt-get install php mysql-server mysql-client php5-mysql libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php-mbstring php5-gd libapache2-mod-php5
```

it will install all necessary things to run php

Comment: P.S Reset yout droplet

Comment: tried this as well as removing apache2 and reinstalling it and there is no error but when i check the files, nothing seems to be installing. also using the 3rd command i get a lot of messages back saying the package is not available.

Comment: type apt-get autoremove apache2 to uninstall it completely

Comment: or you can delete and re-setup your droplet from DigitalOcean